# How to define a format to find UNC path form a text file through PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I want to fetch only the UNC path from a text file. The UNC path always ends with a character combined with number like `P100`, `R101`, `E000`, etc.

Sometimes the UNC path ends with some characters or symbols like

```
\\Localhost\apps\data\logs\P100###
```

I have tried different ways to fetch string starts with `\\` and ends with P100 0R R101 etc. But, unable to achieve this task through PowerShell. Kindly help.

If the UNC path is `\\Localhost\apps\data\logs\P100###` or `\\Localhost\apps\data\logs\P100Target`, then I only need `\\Localhost\apps\data\logs\P100` through my script. Whatever extra character or symbols must be eliminated.

Comment: So does the path *always* end with a character combined with number or does it *sometimes* end with some characters or symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation:

```sh
# Sample paths
$paths = 
  '\\Localhost\apps\data\logs\Q102###',
  '\\App.Abc.test.test\apps\GS\Data\PKG-SCCM\GoogleChrome_19.012.20034_MUI_E100###',
  '\\App.Abc.test.test\apps\GS\Data\PKG-SCCM\Flashplayer_19.012.20034_MUI_R101[Target]'

$paths -replace '(?<=\\[^\\]*[A-Z]\d{3})[^\\]+$'
```

<sup>Note: Use `-creplace` instead of `-replace` to make matching case-*sensitive*, so that only *uppercase* (English) letters match. PowerShell is generally case-*insensitive* by default.</sup>

To apply the above to *file* input (the individual lines from a file), use something like
`(Get-Content file.txt) -replace '...'`

The above yields (note that what comes after `Q102`, `E100` and `R101` in the input strings has been removed):

```
\\Localhost\apps\data\logs\Q102
\\App.Abc.test.test\apps\GS\Data\PKG-SCCM\GoogleChrome_19.012.20034_MUI_E100
\\App.Abc.test.test\apps\GS\Data\PKG-SCCM\Flashplayer_19.012.20034_MUI_R101
```

The `-replace` operation considers only the *last* component of the input paths, and therefore works with any path, as long as the last component is preceded by `\`.

For an explanation of the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) passed to `-replace` and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/v79alB/1).

Comment: `Thanks. It is working now and I'm able to build the expressions  by following your suggested URL 

https://regex101.com/r/v79alB/1

`

Answer (score -1):

If you have a path to each of your text files you could use Split-Path.

```
Split-Path -Path "\\UNC\Folder\Folder\P100\Example.txt" -Parent
```

[PowerShell: Split-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the intent is not to get the _parent_ path (which is what your `Split-Path` command does), but to trim trailing characters from the file-name part of the given paths.